# How to place an link of "application manager" on the home screen?

Tags: settings, home-screen, application-manager

I'm going many times daily to Application manager in Settings.

(Android 4.2.2:)
Settings --> More --> Application manager

Is it possible to put a link of "Application Manager" on the Home screen in order to avoid passing by Settings?
(I don't want to install external application managers apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be possible using a shortcut to the corresponding activity. Launchers like *Apex* have that feature built-in, for others you can use helpers like [Activity Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.szalkowski.activitylauncher). Both allow you to browse your apps, dive into their activities, and chose one to create a shortcut for. In your case, you would need to investigate the *Settings* app – and I'm pretty sure you'll find the matching activity.

**Edit:** Just in case you might miss that as well, you'll have to tap the entry of the app in question (here: *Settings*) to open the list of its activities.

Comment: Thank you Izzy. I installed Activity Launcher but unfortunately no Settings and no Application Manager in Recent activities or All activities.

Comment: I'm 100% sure "Settings" is in there, as I'm using that myself (both ways: on some devices with *Apex*, on one with *Activity Launcher*). It might be called differently (e.g. localized, which it is in my case) – so also watch out for that (and the corresponding icon).

Comment: But did you see also the Application Manager? (I already have the settings shortcut from android)

Comment: I didn't check that one explicitly, but it must be part of Settings. Activity names are not always that clear, you might have to try several until finding the right one.

Comment: I found the application manager link in an app with the name Swapps. With swapps you can open a list of starred apps or links. I was happy to see the application manager shortcut within it.

Comment: Swapps probably does exactly the same. I've just checked with *Activity Manager*, and found three entries for the *Application Manager* straight (in *Settings* – or rather "Einstellungen", as app names are localized).

Comment: I didn't see the dropdown arrow before Settings till now. Thank you very much. This resolved my problem. Still have to find which of the 2 application managers entries I have to take.

Comment: Oh, *that's* why. OK, I'll update my answer to point that out, so it will be clearer for others who might miss it as well :) Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Found another, even better, app to do it: QuickShortcutMaker (because with this app you can also change icon and rename the shortcut). Tnx again Izzy for showing me the way how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Completely forgot about that one! Yes, indeed :) Enjoy!